# Is it permissible for a widow to marry her husband's nephew?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Is it permissible for a widow to marry her husband's nephew?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming she is passed the mourning period, then yes - there is nothing to prevent this union (assuming all other things are as per Islamic rules).

Since the person is no longer her husband, and assuming the husband's nephew is not otherwise related to the wife - the husband's nephew would just be as another Muslim person, and as she is no longer related to him this union is perfectly fine.